# Avoid shuffle while writing data into a partitioned table from another partitioned table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, databricks

I am trying to read from a partitioned delta table, perform some narrow transformations, and write it into a new delta table which is partitioned on the same fields.

```
Table A (partitioned on col1, col2) -> Table B (partitioned on col1, col2)
```

Since the partitioning strategy is the same and there are no wide transformations, my assumption is that shuffle is not needed here

Do I need to specify some special options while reading or writing to ensure that the shuffle operation is not triggered for this?

I tried to read the data normally and write it back using `df_B.write.partitionBy("col1", "col2")...` but the shuffle still seems to be the bottleneck

Comment: Are you sure that shuffle is a problem here? I did a quick check on my env and stages for shuffle were generated but later during execution Spark skipped them. You can check your SparkUI, if you find that shuffle is real and some data are being exchanged please add some screenshots and code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. I was seeing a shuffle happening because of the Delta Table property `spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled`. This may not be needed now since the partition strategy of source and destination is the same now.